# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error How do I solve this?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I need some help. I'm using Java with Springboot and I'm working on a project that essentially displays info from a database (book titles, authors, language, and so on) onto a webpage, and navigating the website allows me to make changes to the database like edit an entry, create a new entry, show an entry, or delete an entry.

It worked just fine till I had to shut down my computer, and then when I returned and tried to run that project again, it gives me the error below along with a lot of other text. I restarted the server, ran it in debug mode, nothing seemed to work. It's almost as if I broke some kind of connection that was there before, or I deleted something that I wasn't supposed to have deleted. I just can't figure out what it could be. I was hoping anyone can tell me what I might've done wrong so I can reverse it and have it up and running again.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2020-03-16 23:06:05.766[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m49106[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Note that I did not learn about "hibernate" directly, and only heard of this term when I saw this error and tried Googling for an answer. I tried some of the other solutions mentioned on stackoverflow for people with a very similar problem but it doesn't work for me (namely, adding a specific dependency regarding hibernate, but I don't remember the details of it right now off the top of my head).

Below is some of the code I used for the various packages:

*Property*

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema2 
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=root 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
```

In the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.blank.mvc2</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mvc2</name>
    <description>mvc2</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In the models package:
    import java.util.Date;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.PreUpdate;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

@Entity
@Table(name="books2")
public class Book {
```

In the repositories package:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
```

In the Services package:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BookService {
```

In the controllers package:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class BooksController {
```

Mind you, I did this project already, and was doing it again for practice, and both projects worked before, but now neither project works. It was working fine till I rebooted my computer (no updates on the computer itself during that time). If you want more info, let me know. I just need help with figuring this out right now as it makes no sense to me why it would work one minute and then by simply turning the computer on/off it doesn't work the next minute.

Comment: Can you add your property file. Need to see Database configuration

Comment: I'm going to add it to the main post because it doesn't format well as a response in the comments. it's at the bottom.

Comment: I presume you are able to connect database explicitly?

Comment: I have the database in front of me, i'm using WorkBench. I have entries in it from when it last worked the other day.

Comment: Would you try replacing driver class to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver and remove scope from MysqlConnector in POM.xml

Comment: I went to the pom.xml file, but I don't see a driver class (maybe I don't know what it is?), but I do see the mysql-connector-java with scope of runtime beneath that.

Comment: Driver class is in property file...

Comment: Ok so I replaced the driver class with what you said (com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver) and I removed the <scope>runtime</scope> which came right after <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>, but I have the same error as before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209736/discussion-between-swarit-agarwal-and-nocardiologist1).

Comment: Hibernate can't connect to your database. Check if database exists on the server. Also check if you have specified correct username and password.

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace to your message and not only the snippet.

Comment: Hey Ken, I'm not sure how to check that, but I can tell you that the database has information that I entered into it when the program was working just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so nothing was working and after doing more digging around online, I found a solution but didn't understand how to implement it or if it would even work. Sure enough, I found a Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO0IaGrlGPc) in which he explains it step by step and how to solve it.

TLDR: I initially had `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema` in my properties, but was getting several errors, one of which was EDT wasn't a recognized time zone. That seemed to be what caused the other errors.

So what I have in properties now is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book-schema?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

The program now works just as it was working before. (I think that perhaps Daylight Saving Time on March 8 might've played a role? I don't know, but it was working fine and then suddenly it's saying it doesn't recognize EDT.)

Thank you all who tried to help me solve this.